# Draw an image with custom Size and Rotation into a CustomPaint in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

How can I draw an image to a `customPaint()` specifying its size and rotation in Flutter?
Normally with only `drawImage()` the image gets drawn with its dimensions being its dimensions in pixels. For example, a 40x40 pixels image gets drawn with dimensions of 40 by 40. How can I draw the same image but for example with a size of 80x80 and a rotation of 120°? I've tried `drawAtlas` but I couldn't find anything online.

This is the code I have to draw. (It draws a 20x20 rectangle at the top-right of the screen).

```
class ParticlePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<GameObject> objects;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {


    canvas.drawRect(

        Rect.fromCenter(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            center: Offset(0.0, 0.0)),

        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..blendMode = BlendMode.darken);
    }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  ParticlePainter(this.objects);
}
```

To get the image I'm using the code in this video: [Custom Paint in Flutter](https://youtu.be/vvI_NUXK00s?t=166)

```
Future<Image> _loadImage(File file) async{
   final data = await file.readAsBytesSync();
   return await decodeImageFromList(data);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some more code of what you're doing?

Comment: @DerekFredrickson Ok! Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can rotate the canvas itself in your paint function. My code is below.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ParticlePainter extends CustomPainter {
  // final List<GameObject> objects;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.save();

    final degrees = 120;
    final radians = degrees * math.pi / 180;

    canvas.rotate(radians);

    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
          center: Offset(
            0.0,
            0.0,
          ),
        ),
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..blendMode = BlendMode.darken);

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  // ParticlePainter(this.objects);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Yay"),
      ),
      body: CustomPaint(
        child: Container(),
        painter: ParticlePainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For me, this causes the box to go off screen a bit, but I hope it is enough for you to move forward. If you're doing something easy, you might be able to use either `Transform.rotate` or `RotatedBox` and wrap your `CustomPaint` in it.

Comment: Thank you! But I've a problem, This solves the issues in a certain sense, but at the same time if I wanted to draw multiple rotated and scaled images, how should I do? Should I rotate and scale the canvas everytime?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to draw multiple images on a single canvas, and rotate them all separately?

Comment: @DerekFredrickson Yes, rotate and scale them independently from each other

Comment: Gotcha. Let me do some more research because I'm not sure. Is there a reason it all needs to be on the same canvas? I'm not super familiar with the custom painting in Flutter

Comment: @DerekFredrickson It's a "render engine" for a 2D game, so I need to have multiple objects rendered at the same time

Comment: @fabriziog Have you considered using https://github.com/flame-engine/flame? I was poking through their code to see how they handle it

Answer (score 2):

It's a long time since the question was asked but I want to fulfill the answer for future readers, as the above answer does not answer it for multiple objects.

There is only `canvas.rotate()` and `canvas.transform()` to rotate anything in the flutter canvas and there is `canvas.scale()` to scale them.

now if you want to rotate one object 120, and another 40 degrees you need to draw them inside a `canvas.save()` ... `canvas.restore()` block. then your objects will be rotated at a different angles. look at the below code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

const kCanvasSize = 300.0;

class ImageInsideRectPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageInsideRectPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageInsideRectPageState createState() => _ImageInsideRectPageState();
}

class _ImageInsideRectPageState extends State<ImageInsideRectPage> {
  ui.Image? image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _load('assets/img.png');
    super.initState();
  }

  void _load(String path) async {
    var bytes = await rootBundle.load(path);
    image = await decodeImageFromList(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 2)),
          height: kCanvasSize,
          width: kCanvasSize,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ImageInsideRectangle(context: context, image: image),
            child: SizedBox.expand(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageInsideRectangle extends CustomPainter {
  ImageInsideRectangle({required this.context, required this.image});
  ui.Image? image;
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    canvas.clipRRect(ui.RRect.fromRectXY(
      Rect.fromPoints(Offset(0, 0), Offset(kCanvasSize - 4, kCanvasSize - 4)),
      0,
      0,
    ));
    Paint greenBrush = Paint()..color = Colors.greenAccent;
    if (image != null) {
      canvas.save();
      rotate(
          canvas: canvas,
          cx: image!.width.toDouble() / 2,
          cy: image!.height.toDouble() / 2,
          angle: -0.3);
      canvas.scale(kCanvasSize / image!.height);
      canvas.drawImage(image!, Offset(0, 0), greenBrush);
      canvas.restore();
    }
    canvas.save();
    rotate(canvas: canvas, cx: 200 + 50, cy: 100 + 50, angle: 0.5);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(200, 100, 100, 100), greenBrush);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  void rotate(
      {required Canvas canvas,
      required double cx,
      required double cy,
      required double angle}) {
    canvas.translate(cx, cy);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-cx, -cy);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

This way you can rotate multiple objects in multiple directions. also, there is an example of loading an image from local asset and rotating the image around its own center.